# HtmlAgilityPack - Attributes property always empty

Tags: .net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to parse some html and I'm trying to extract the style attribute of an image tag. Here is some sample code:

```
  Dim hd As New HtmlDocument()
  hd.LoadHtml("<img style='float:left;' />")
  Dim s As String = hd.DocumentNode.GetAttributeValue("style", String.Empty)
```

The problem is that the string `s` is always empty, and when I inspect `hd.DocumentNode` in debug I find that the attributes collection is also empty and HasAttributes is set to false.

Could this be to do with the way I am populating the html document object with a scrap of html rather than a complete document?

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I had made an assumption that because the html I had loaded was only a single element the document node would BE that single element. In fact I still needed to select the element using XPath before I had a reference to it and was able to access it's attributes. Solution:

```
Dim hd As New HtmlDocument()
hd.LoadHtml("<img style='float:left;' />")
Dim s As String = hd.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img").GetAttributeValue("style", String.Empty)
```